# When I disable proxy , I am no more able to connect to the internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, proxy

I am using windows 10 on a work laptop, when I am at workplace I need to connect through proxy, so when I go home I disable the proxy to be able to access the internet through wifi or hotspot, but the internet notification icon gives this yellow exclamation that says "no internet access" .... any help ?

edit:
I tried trouble shooting the problem , It gave the error :

"Windows can't communicate with the device or resource (primary DNS server)" error while connecting to wireless network

Comment: I don't know but generally speaking, if you disable a proxy itself, and the software is still using the proxy then you'll get the error.. so you'd have to tell the software(be it windows or some program within windows), not to use the proxy. I haven't seen an option to tell windows generally to use a proxy. Though I haven't used windows 10 much.  Perhaps you can add some info about where the proxy option was set. As well as where you disabled it. And what the proxy is, like is it squid web proxy, or some other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some troobleshooting ... I only needed to configure tcp to get DNS server automatically
**https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2779064**